# Docker container file system access

Tags: docker

When we install any application there creates lots of file structure and also generates logs file in specified path of the application. When we are running same application in docker container , its also creates those files. How can we access those file . As I know we can use docker exec command with bash to interact in command prompt or terminal but is it possible to access same using winscp or gui based any 3rd party tools.

Comment: use volume mount or you need to install and configure ssh on the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) on the container, so the "locally" generated docker files can be accessed from the host. For example:

```
docker run -v host_dir:container_dir yourDocker (...)
```

Your docker's process will save the files to his *local* `container_dir`, and you could access them via your host's `host_dir`.